# Can't find the mistake in this proof that the affine line is disconnected

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As the title suggests, I can't seem to find the mistake in this "proof" that the affine line is disconnected.

Let $X = \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$, and consider the element $(x - 1) \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, then by one of the exercises in Hartshorne, $\text{Supp }(x - 1) = \{P \in X | (x - 1)_P \neq 0 \}$ is a closed set. This is the set $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1 \backslash \{1\}$. Then this would also be an open set, since the set $\{1\}$ corresponds to the maximal ideal $(x - 1) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. This shows that $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ is disconnected.

Comment: $\ne 0$ should be $= 0$.

Comment: @Sasha I think the $\ne$ is correct, http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01AS

Comment: This is correct when you consider a sheaf. In your case the appropriate sheaf is the cokernel of the map $x-1$, and its stalk is nonzero iff $x-1$ is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of support, $(x-1)_P$ denotes the germ of $x-1$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$, not the image in the residue field at $P$.  Concretely in this case, that means the image of $x-1$ in the localization of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ at the prime $P$, rather than the image of $x-1$ in the quotient $\mathbb{C}[x]/P$.  With this definition, the support of $x-1$ is actually all of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$, since its image is not $0$ in any localization of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ (indeed, since $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a domain, the map from $\mathbb{C}[x]$ to any localization that doesn't invert $0$ is injective).